# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in Azure

Tags: c#, azure

I have an Azure API app service. 
I have added * to CORS settings within it.

I have another web app in Azure where I make calls to Azure API app.

Example : https://XXXXXX.XXXXXX.net/api/XXXXXX

The calls work when the api is working with small video files but whenever a video is more than 20mb, I always get -

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access. 
The response had HTTP status code 500
```

The API accepts an ID from the POST request and works with videos in a folder in Azure Media storage. This error doesn't happen when the video is under 20mb.

Any idea what the problem could be ?

I keep getting

**500 - The request timed out.
The web server failed to respond within the specified time.**
as Response  and the CORS error on console.

The API call works and does its stuff though.

Here is the web.config looks like

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" maxRequestLength="5097151" executionTimeout="1800" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="5097151000"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <httpProtocol>

    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no CORS header coming back because the response is HTTP 500, most probably due to the payload exceeding the maximum size allowed.

Amend your `web.config` with a larger value:

```xml
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <security>
         <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="{value In Bytes}"/>
         </requestFiltering>
      </security>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

[From MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits/#configuration) (emphasis mine) —

> #### maxAllowedContentLength
>
> Optional uint attribute. 
>   Specifies the maximum length of content in a request, in bytes. 
>   **The default value is 30000000, which is approximately 28.6MB.**

Comment: Hey. Thanks for that but it still didn't solve my issue. I added a limit of 5gb to maxAllowedContentLength but still no luck. On the response I keep getting 500 - The request timed out.
The web server failed to respond within the specified time. However, the api call works and does the other stuff.

Comment: Enable failed request tracing maybe it tells you more - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/01/27/enable-failed-reuqest-tracing-for-an-azure-app-service-web-app/

Answer (score 1):

If there's no CORS header coming back and the CORS setting *is set*, then probably the application is crashing due to an exception, and it's too big to be deserialized. That was my issue.

Try debugging it with the azure cli.